# How to transform second row to column and add prefix to column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame with two rows and would like to make the second row a column and keep the original column name with an added prefix.

```
Current df

Date       Name   ID
14/1/2012  Jane   420
14/1/2012  Sam    666


Goal df  
 
Date       Name   ID   Date2       Name2  ID2
14/1/2012  Jane   420  14/1/2012   Sam    666 

where the added prefix is '2'.
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is just two rows, you can hard code your solution with `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[[0]], 
           df.iloc[[-1]].add_suffix("2").reset_index(drop=True)
           ], 
           axis="columns"
          )

        Date    Name    ID  Date2     Name2 ID2
0   14/1/2012   Jane    420 14/1/2012   Sam 666
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more concise way, but you can manually flatten the dataframe like this:

```
import itertools

new_cols=[]
for n in range(len(df)):
    new_cols.extend(f"{col}_{n}" for col in df.columns)

records = df.values
values = list(itertools.chain(*records))

df_output = pd.DataFrame(data=[values], columns=new_cols)
```

output:

```
      Date_0 Name_0  ID_0     Date_1 Name_1  ID_1
0  14/1/2012   Jane   420  14/1/2012    Sam   666
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index ==0 :
        print("slipped first row")
    else:
        extcol1= "Date{}".format(index+1)
        extcol2= "Name{}".format(index+1)
        extcol3= "ID{}".format(index+1)
        df[extcol1] =row["Date"]
        df[extcol2] =row["Name"]
        df[extcol3] =row["ID"]
        df.drop(index)
```